# How can I collect a list of strings to a map, where each string is a key?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11, collectors

I am working on an exercise to count words in a phrase.

I have a regex I'm happy with to split the phrase into word tokens, so I can complete the work with basic loops - no problem.

But I'd like to use streams to collect the strings into a map instead of using basic loops.

I need each word as a *key* and, for now, I'd just like the integer `1` as the value.
Having done some research online I should be able to collect the list of words into a map like so:

```
public Map<String, Integer> phrase(String phrase) {
    List<String> words = //... tokenized words from phrase
    return words.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(word -> word, 1));
}
```

I have tried this, and several variations (casting `word`, using `Function.identity()`), but keep getting the error:

```
The method toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> s) -> {}, int)
```

Any example I've found to date only uses the string as the value, but otherwise indicates that this should be OK.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: use `word -> 1` instead of just `1`, because a function is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get over the compilation error, you need:

```
return words.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(word -> word, word -> 1));
```

however, this would result in all the values of the `Map` being 1, and if you have duplicate elements in `words`, you'll get an exception.

You'll need to either use `Collectors.groupingBy` or `Collectors.toMap` with a merge function to handle duplicate values.

For example

```
return words.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word -> word, Collectors.counting()));
```

or

```
return words.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(word -> word, word -> 1, Integer::sum));
```